# Firebase database not displaying data to ListView but writing to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm receiving an error:

> 12378-12378/info.androidhive.firebase W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for artistName found on class info.androidhive.firebase.Artist2

The data is writing to Firebase database but it isn't displaying in the `ListView`.

Please see my code below:

```
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ArtistList2 extends ArrayAdapter<Artist2> {

private Activity context; //context activity
private List<Artist2> artistList2; //list will store all the artists


//constructor parsing context and artist list
public ArtistList2(Activity context, List<Artist2> artistList2) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout2, artistList2); //passing context, layout file and the artist list
    this.context = context; //initialising variables
    this.artistList2 = artistList2;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { //over ride get view method
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater(); //layout inflator object

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout2,null,true); //creating list view object to inflate the xml list layout

    TextView textViewName2 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName2); //create text view for the name
    TextView textViewGenre2 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewGenre2); //create text view for the genres

    Artist2 artist2 = artistList2.get(position);
    //Artist artist2 = artistList2.get(position); //gets the artists particular position

    textViewName2.setText(artist2.getArtistName2()); //set name value to the corresponding text view
    textViewGenre2.setText(artist2.getArtistGenre2()); //set genre value to the corresponding text view

    return listViewItem;

}
```

}

package info.androidhive.firebase;

public class Artist2 {

```
String artistId2;
String artistName2;
String artistGenre2;


public Artist2(){}

public Artist2(String artistId2, String artistName2, String artistGenre2) {
    this.artistId2 = artistId2;
    this.artistName2 = artistName2;
    this.artistGenre2 = artistGenre2;
}

public String getArtistId2() {
    return artistId2;
}

public String getArtistName2() {
    return artistName2;
}

public String getArtistGenre2() {
    return artistGenre2;
}
```

}

public class WishListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
//Declarations of variables
EditText editTextName2;
Button buttonAdd2;
Spinner spinnerGenres2;

//Database reference object
DatabaseReference databaseArtists2;

//Declaration of list view for the adapter
ListView listViewArtists2; //retrieves this from the xml
List<Artist2> artistList2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wish_list2);


    //gets the database reference object and passes artists - the parameter
    databaseArtists2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artists2");
    //Declarations of textviews, buttons and spinners
    editTextName2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName2);
    buttonAdd2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddArtist2);
    spinnerGenres2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGenres2);

    listViewArtists2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewArtists2);

    artistList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    //onclick listener to the button - calls the method add artist
    buttonAdd2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            addArtist2();

        }});

}


@Override
protected void onStart() { //overriding on start method
    super.onStart();


    databaseArtists2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //database  reference object attached to the value event listener, passing a new value event listener
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //when anything changed in the db
            artistList2.clear(); //clears artist list
            for(DataSnapshot artistSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //everything that is contained within db reference object will be displayed in the snapshot
               // Artist artist2 = artistSnapshot.getValue(Artist2.class); //gets all values of the artist class for the snapshot
                Artist2 artist2 = artistSnapshot.getValue(Artist2.class);
                //artistList2.add(artist2);
                artistList2.add(artist2);


            }

           // ArtistList2 adapter2 = new ArtistList(WishListActivity.this, artistList2);
            ArtistList2 adapter2 = new ArtistList2(WishListActivity.this, artistList2);
            listViewArtists2.setAdapter(adapter2); //this method is executed when new information is added to the database
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { //when anything removed in the db

        }
    });

}
//Add artist method
private void addArtist2() {
    String name = editTextName2.getText().toString().trim();
    String genre = spinnerGenres2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //checks to see if the name field is left empty
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) { //if name field isnt empty, the information will be stored in firebase

        //using the post method to store values within
        String id = databaseArtists2.push().getKey();

        //Create new artist
        Artist artist2 = new Artist(id,name,genre);

        //Use set value method to store the artist within the unique generated id value
        databaseArtists2.child(id).setValue(artist2);

        //Prompts the user that the information has been added
        Toast.makeText(this, "Book added to Wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{ //if the name field is empty, the user will be prompted to enter in a name
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Book Info",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for artistName found on class info.androidhive.firebase.Artist2

Because the Firebase SDK when deserializing is looking into your database after a field named `artistName` that actualy does **not** exist since in your model class all your fileds are ending with `2` (see the last character?). To solve this, you either change the name of the fiels in your model class to match the one in the database or you delete the actual data from the server, and add fresh one according to the fields that exist in your class. You can also use an annotation in front of your getter like this:

```
@PropertyName("artistName")
public String getArtistName2() { return artistName2; }
```